# How to use InMemory table parameter in RunBaseBarch class?

Tags: variables, batch-processing, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I pass by parm method a InMemory table in my custom class exended `RunBaseBatch`.

But I not able to see this table,  I can use and see other passed variable (like string or int), but I lost the reference to InMemory Table.

If I not extend **RunBaseBatch** I'm able to use and see the InMemory table passed.

It's possible to use InMemory table in RunBaseBatch class? Otherwise there is any way?

Thanks.

Comment: Consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the following method:

```
protected boolean canSwapBetweenCS()
{
    return false;
}
```

Depending on where your in-memory table creates its values it might loose it is reference to the data (set with `setTmpData`). The methods signals it does not like throttling data between client and server.

Also don't expect it to work in batch, if the records was created outside the scope of the `run` method.

Comment: Thanks @Jan B. Kjeldsen, I create a _Temp_ table outside (before) the **run** method of batch class.

Comment: Then you will have call `setTmpData` in your class, before using the temp table. The easy way out is to make a method of the class with that purpose. Call it after creating the records, but before calling run. Also, you have to be on the same tier (i.e. no Server attribute on class).

Comment: @Thanks Jan B. Kjeldsen for info about Tmp table.